# Configure buttons on one form from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that has a main form which has 10 buttons that are user configurable.
I have another form with which to configure those 10 buttons actions.

What is the best way for me to configure these 10 buttons?
Currently, I'm passing the 10 buttons as a List to the second form, and link them to the appropriate combobox tag.
The problem is if sometime in the future I decide to add a button or rearrange them, I'll have to rewrite the code. Anyone know a better way?

```
    private readonly List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes;
    private readonly List<ComboBox> comboBoxes;
    public Shortcut_Buttons (List<string> stringsList, List<Button> sButtons)
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        pictureBoxes = Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToList();
        comboBoxes = Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().ToList();

        if (pictureBoxes.Count != sButtons.Count)
            throw new ArgumentException("Not enough Buttons/Pictureboxes.");

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var pictureBox in pictureBoxes)
        {
            pictureBox.BackgroundImage = sButtons[i++].BackgroundImage;
        }



        i = 0;
        foreach (var comboBox in comboBoxes)
        {
            comboBox.DataSource = stringsList;
            comboBox.Tag = sButtons[i++];
            comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += SetShortcutButton;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing directly the form by getting instance?
Like:

```
private static MainForm _this = null;
public static MainForm Instance { get { return _this; } } 

public MainForm()
{
_this = this;
...
}
```

Meanwhile in another place:

MainForm.Instace.somePublicComponents....

Comment: I'd rather not couple forms if I can avoid it, after all I can also just pass the main form to the secondary form and let it handle it.